# Rails default behavior: Why is Rails not generating different Etags by default or returning 304 Not Modified?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http-caching, http-status-code-304, http-status-code-200

I am inspecting a Rails response. No http headers have been purposefully set to be returned from the server.

The response includes `Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate` and `Etag`. The response is a 200 no matter how many times I make the same request or within how short a period of time.

My questions are:

1. How is the Etag being generated if I didn't set a `stale?` or
   `fresh_when` in the response? The Etag is always the same for this
   endpoint.
2. Regardless of how the Etag is being generated, if it is always the same, why isn't the server noticing that the Etag is the always
   the same and responding with a 304 rather than a 200?

Thank you

Comment: any update on this question ?

Answer (score 0):

- One of the reason might be the presence of `mini_profiler`, as by default that gem overrides some cache related headers ([see here](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler#caching-behavior) why and how to fix it).
- Another one is that you have `config.action_controller.perform_caching = false`.